# ¿Alguna forma de obtener los elementos de una tabla como una matriz? Selenium + Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Estoy obteniedo las celdas de una tabla de esta forma con Selenium. Lo que estoy consiguiendo es una lista con el valor de cada celda.

```
def seleccionar_productos(driver):     
 rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tabla']/tbody/tr") 

 cells = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tabla']/tbody/tr/td")

 column_count = len(cells)/len(rows)     

 print ("filas=%s columnas=%s" % (row_count, column_count) )
 print( cells[0].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
 print( rows[0].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Me gustaria poder conseguir lo mismo pero en forma de matríz porque me resulta mas facil de manejar

El resultado de esto es:

```
filas=10 columnas=14.0
```

El valor de `cells[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')` me da el valor de la celda (Estupendo).

Pero el valor de `rows[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')` es intratable, algo así.

```
<td>Text1</td> <td>Text2</td> <td>Text3</td> <td>Text4</td> <td>Text4</td>....
```

La variable cells tiene valores desde 0 a 140

Y me gustaría poder tenerlo de esta forma

```
cells[coll][row].get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Donde Coll tendrá valores entre 0 y 14, y row entre 0 y 10

Y si no alguna forma de extraer los valores de la variable "rows".

¿Alguna ídea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final he hecho esto:

```
def crear_matriz(lista, n_filas, n_columnas):
 matriz = []
 count = 0
 for i in range(n_filas):
  matriz.append([])
  for j in range(n_columnas):
   matriz[i].append(lista[count])
   count+=1   
 return matriz




def seleccionar_productos(driver):     
 rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tabla']/tbody/tr") 

 cells = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='tabla']/tbody/tr/td")

 column_count = len(cells)//len(rows)     

 print ("filas=%s columnas=%s" % (row_count, column_count) )

 matriz = crear_matriz(cells, row_count, column_count)

 for i in range(row_count):   
    print("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s" %
          (
          matriz[i][0].get_attribute('innerHTML'), 
          matriz[i][1].get_attribute('innerHTML'), 
          matriz[i][2].get_attribute('innerHTML'), 
          matriz[i][6].get_attribute('innerHTML'), 
          matriz[i][7].get_attribute('innerHTML'), 
          matriz[i][8].get_attribute('innerHTML'),
          matriz[i][9].get_attribute('innerHTML')
          )
          )
```

No sé si es la mejor forma de hacerlo pero lo cierto es que me gusta bastante mas que la otra. Si alguien sabe como obtener esto usando directamente las herramientas de Selenium sería estupendo que lo comentara por aquí.